# Creating temporary layers in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, layers, in-memory

Is it possible to create temporary layers in ArcGIS Pro?

All layers seem to have to be created using the geodatabase format.

For example, if I want to buffer around a point do I need to create a new feature class in the geodatabase to mark the area I want buffered and then create a buffer layer that is either saved as a shapefile or feature layer in the geodatabase again?

Comment: Yes you can.... May be you  should add a bit more detail?

Comment: Updated above. Not a big issue but I love the use of temporary layers in QGIS and haven't been able to recreate in Arc. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write output data to memory, see: [Write geoprocessing output to memory](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/the-in-memory-workspace.htm)

> Writing geoprocessing outputs to memory is an alternative to writing
> output to a geodatabase or file-based format. It is often
> significantly faster than writing to on-disk formats. Data written
> into memory is temporary and is deleted when the application is
> closed, so it is an ideal location to write intermediate data created
> in a ModelBuilder model or Python script.

But I dont know of an easy way of creating an empty "Temporary scratch layer" as in QGIS. I usually create a new feature class in the default geodatabase. (Which in ArcGIS Pro takes longer than doing the entire work/analysis in QGIS...)

Comment: I like the QGIS method.  The ArcGIS suggestion is to create a default poly, line & point layer in the default geodatabase, and store temporary stuff in it, then periodically go in and delete the contents.